Does there exist any function (, ) such that $\frac{∂ f}{∂ x} = $ and $\frac{∂ f}{∂ y} = ^2$ ? Use Clairaut's theorem to prove this
I have this question I wonder about. I know that I can take the mixed partials and that they do not equal each other, meaning that the function does not satisfy Clairaut's theorem, and is not continuous, but I am not sure how to prove the function does not exist. Thank you for the help!

The proof is via contradiction.
If you assume that such an $f$ exists, then by Clairaut's theorem we would have $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$. However, as you have noted you get different results if you differentiate the given derivatives with respect to the other variable.
So since Clairaut's theorem has been broken, we have a contradiction on our assumption, meaning that $f$ must not exist.

got it, so simply because their mixed partials are not equal we can assume that the function does not exist? this is still tripping me up a little just because i was under the impression that if the mixed partials were not equal it only meant the function isn't continuous? Thank you for the speedy response!

If you want to be more careful about it (which is always a good idea), look carefully at how Clairaut's theorem is stated in your notes. Since we're given first derivatives of $f$, that provides information about the continuity of $f$ as well.

ok, so in this case would I be able to use a limit definition to find that information about continuity of f? I'm still having a hard time understanding the relationship between first derivative and continuity, it seems that the two first derivatives are both continuous. thank you!

Since the partial derivatives are continuous, the function must be differentiable, hence continuous. And note that $f$ must also be $C^2$.

Here the equations are simple enough that you can solve for $f$. From the first equation we obtain (locally) that $f = \frac{1}{2}x^2y + C$. From the second, $f = x^2y + D$. Since these can't both be true, there is no solution to these equations.

thank you! this is very helpful
